# SmartContracts/Solidity: Can anyone see my smartcontract Code? Or is it kept private?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I've been spending some time working on an NFT Game when I realized if other people know my contract methods and ABI they could easily hack the game. So I was just wondering if people can see my Contract Code and get my ABI without me knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write the smart contract, solidity compiler spits out `ABI` and `bytecode`. we use `ABI` to interact with the deployed contract. `Bytecode` is an executable code on EVM and stored on blockchain.

[image]

There are some decompilers to read this bytecode but as far as I know they are not perfectly decompiling the bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't verify the smart contract code, it keeps private.

However, you should take care of ABI code. This is because you'll be using it on frontend to interact your NFT game smart contract, and it'll be easy to find if someone downloads the website.